# Why for(cont=100; cont>=20; cont-=10) returning only one value and not a serie

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Why this code below doesn't return a serie like...100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 and it returns as result the number 10?

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int cont;
 for(cont=100; cont>=20; cont-=10);
 {
   cout<< " "<<cont;
 }
 cout<< "\n";
 system("pause");
}
```

And sorry for my dumb question.. I started to learn c++ now

Thanks

Comment: Because the semicolon behind the loop...

Comment: Replace `"\n"` with `std::endl`

Comment: And learn *right now how to* **use the debugger** !!!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `"\n"` is perfectly fine, why would you want to call `std::flush` explicitly ?

Comment: Thank you very much guys! Yes I need to learn how to use the debugger.. I'm using cdev and also visual studio..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for(cont=100; cont>=20; cont-=10);
                                 ↑
```

Remove this `;`.

Your code is identical to:

```
for(cont=100; cont>=20; cont-=10) { }
{
   cout<< " "<<cont;
}
```

The loop will continue to subtract 10 from `count` until `count>=20` is not satisfied, then it'll print the value of `cont`, which will be 10.

Tip: Use a debugger, it's your best friend.

Comment: Perfect man... thank you for your quick answer.. I need to pay more attention on commas

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake has already be pointed out (a stray `;` after your `for ();` loop), however the root cause is somewhat more subtle:

*Variables should be declared in the **tightest scope** possible*.

If we obey this guideline, we get:

```
int main()
{
    for(int cont=100; cont>=20; cont-=10);
    {
        std::cout << " " << cont; // COMPILER ERROR: unknown "cont"
    }
    std::cout<< "\n";
}
```

and a compile-time error is always less costly to track down that a runtime one.

Answer (score 3):

The semicolon after the close parentheses doesn't belong there; it's being interpreted as the entire body of the loop.

Comment: I need to mark one answer as the correct one.. but thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Because of the semicolon after closed parantheses. The semicolon after it means that the loop has no body because the semicolon is the end of any statement.